# Creating a new dataset based on values in another dataset pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataset that is structured as:

[image]

As you can see in header the values are same after `/` sign i.e. `group_activity`, `revenue_freq`, `revenue`, `monthly - calc'd` and before `/` the name of that group is written i.e. `dairy`, `livestock` etc.

I'm writing a logic in Python that first check if there is any value available for example in the first row `dairy` and `livestock` doesn't have any value but `poultry` is populated. So when this is detected then 
I want to structure those values as:

[image]

Here the `Sr. Number` is a a number to keep track of how many different types of activities are in a row. Starting with `IA[x]` where `x` can be `01-13`.

How should I do it? To see the above data in a sheet here is the [GOOGLE SHEET LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11eoFm-mDat6OBd11aRiNpv_ByVpeUknbjKAfjcg6AZ0/edit?usp=sharing) where I've two sheets `Input` and `Output`

Comment: You can do `df1['colname'].loc[df2['other column'] is not None] = any_value` for startes

Comment: @jezrael I've added the same data in a google sheet and you can see it here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11eoFm-mDat6OBd11aRiNpv_ByVpeUknbjKAfjcg6AZ0/edit?usp=sharing the reason why I've shared data in this form is because it's a huge dataset and I've only picked a sample that present the problem I'm solving in a neat format.

Comment: @jezrael there are two sheets input and output. It's in output and `Sr. Number` is just an auto increment number.

Comment: In the output sheet I've just updated that. So the Sr. Number for this row should be `IA01` as there is no `Livestock` and `dairy`. And for the very next row as you can see we have `livestock` and `poultry` so it'll be `IA01` and `IA02`

Comment: @jezrael for starters let's do it like you are suggesting. If you have a solution for that please do post it. The data set has a lot of activities like poultry, livestock etc so `Sr. Number` is a way to keep track of how many `IA` are there in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is necessary preprocessing columns names for `MultiIndex` - first level by values before `/` and second values same for each first level - so create helper DataFrame `df1` by [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('Sample Dataset - Input.csv')

df1 = df.columns.to_series().str.split('/', expand=True)
df1[['a','b','c']] = df1[0].str.partition(' monthly ')
df1[1] = df1[1].str.split('_', n=1).str[1]
df1[1] = df1[1].fillna(df1['b'].str.cat(df1['c'].str.strip('>')))
df1['a'] = df1['a'].str.strip('<')
print (df1[['a', 1]])
                                          a                  1
dairy/group_activity                  dairy           activity
dairy/dairy_revenue_freq              dairy       revenue_freq
dairy/dairy_revenue                   dairy            revenue
<dairy monthly - calc'd>              dairy   monthly - calc'd
livestock/group_activity          livestock           activity
livestock/livestock_revenue_freq  livestock       revenue_freq
livestock/livestock_revenue       livestock            revenue
<livestock monthly - calc'd>      livestock   monthly - calc'd
poultry/group_activity              poultry           activity
poultry/poultry_revenue_freq        poultry       revenue_freq
poultry/poultry_revenue             poultry            revenue
<poultry monthly - calc'd>          poultry   monthly - calc'd
```

then create `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html), so possible reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), remove missing values per rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and last new column `Sr. Number` by [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1['a'], df1[1]])

df2 = (df.stack(0)
         .dropna(subset=['activity','revenue','revenue_freq'], how='all')
         .rename_axis(('a','Raw'))
         .reset_index(level=1))
df2.insert(0, 'Sr.Number', df2.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1)
print (df2)
1   Sr.Number        Raw   monthly - calc'd activity  revenue revenue_freq
a                                                                         
0           1    poultry          10000.000      yes  10000.0      monthly
1           1    poultry           2900.000      yes    725.0       weekly
5           1    poultry            250.000       no   3000.0       yearly
6           1  livestock            375.000       no   4500.0       yearly
6           2    poultry            600.000       no    600.0      monthly
7           1  livestock            666.667       no   8000.0       yearly
7           2    poultry           2000.000       no   2000.0      monthly
8           1    poultry           5000.000       no   5000.0      monthly
14          1      dairy           2000.000      yes   2000.0      monthly
19          1    poultry           1920.000       no    480.0       weekly
```

Comment: At `df2 = (df.stack(0)` there is an error: `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha - it means problem with columns names, unfortunately, seems some duplicates. Is possible share `df.columns.to_series().to_csv('cols.csv', index=False)` with real data?

Comment: really appreciate you helping me out here. :) I've updated the output of `df.columns.to_series().to_csv('cols.csv', index=False)` in the google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11eoFm-mDat6OBd11aRiNpv_ByVpeUknbjKAfjcg6AZ0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha - So `print (df.columns)` is `MultiIndex` ?

Comment: Yes it is. This is the output I've got for `print(df.columns)` ---
`MultiIndex(levels=[['% Ag (after)', '% Ag (before)', '% Employment (after)', '% Employment (before)', '% Microbusines (after)', '% Microbusines (before)',...`

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha - ok, I got it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196356/discussion-between-jezrael-and-chaudhry-talha).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Sample Dataset.xlsx')
cols = {'dairy': (1, 4), 'livestock': (5, 8), 'poultry': (9, 12)}

data = list()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    counter = 0
    for group in cols.keys():
        if row[cols[group][0]-1:cols[group][1]].isna().sum() == 0:
            counter+=1
            data.append(['AI'+str(counter).zfill(2), group] + list(row[cols[group][0]-1:cols[group][1]].values))

pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Sr. Number', 'Raw', 'group_activity', 'time period', 'amount', 'monthly_amount'])
```

Result:

```
  Sr. Number        Raw group_activity time period   amount  monthly_amount
0       AI01    poultry            yes     monthly  10000.0       10000.000
1       AI01    poultry            yes      weekly    725.0        2900.000
2       AI01    poultry             no      yearly   3000.0         250.000
3       AI01  livestock             no      yearly   4500.0         375.000
4       AI02    poultry             no     monthly    600.0         600.000
5       AI01  livestock             no      yearly   8000.0         666.667
6       AI02    poultry             no     monthly   2000.0        2000.000
7       AI01    poultry             no     monthly   5000.0        5000.000
8       AI01      dairy            yes     monthly   2000.0        2000.000
9       AI01    poultry             no      weekly    480.0        1920.000
```